# Getting default extra bool value in the select query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How we can specify a bool default value in the select query. I am doing a select using the below mentioned query.

```
 select null as [<TABLENAME>MyTable</TABLENAME>], 'true' [IsCancel], name, age, location from @TempTable
```

Now the 'true' is coming as string. But how can I get an exact true boolean value in the [IsCancel] column ?

The @TempTable contains only 3 columns [name, age, location]. But 
I dont want to put a boolean column in the @TempTable.

```
  declare @TempTable table (
     name       varchar(20) default ''
    ,age            int
    ,location       varchar(50) default ''      
);
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a boolean *data type* - it has `bit`, as per the answers already provided which is *similar* but not exactly the same. Since SQL describes a three-valued logic, a boolean type should support 3 values - true, false and unknown, and a nullable boolean should also support `NULL`. `bit` only supports two values (1 and 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bit` for boolean values:

```
SELECT 
    null as [<TABLENAME>MyTable</TABLENAME>], 
    CONVERT(bit,1) [IsCancel], 
    name, 
    age, 
    location 
FROM @TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT CAST('true' AS BIT) AS [IsCancel]
    SELECT CAST('False' AS BIT) AS [IsCancel]
```